# why $u \in H^2$ imply zero value of jump $[u] = u^{-}-u^{+}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, finite-element-method

in page 13 of [simple DG tutorial](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/pomdapi/Archives/Estime/DYNAS/RESTRICTED/PDF/dg_tutorial_proft.pdf),

it gives following conclusion:

- Define average $w=\frac{1}{2}\left(w^{-}+w^{+}\right)$ and recall jump $[w]=w^{-}*w^{+}$ then
  $$
  [a b]=[a]\{b\}+\{a\}[b]
  $$
- **confusing conclusion :** since $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ and $v \in H^1(\Omega)$,
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  & -\sum_{i=1}^m \int_{e_i}\left[\nabla u \cdot n_i\right]\{v\}=0, \\
  & -\sum_{i=1}^m \int_{e_i}\left\{\nabla v \cdot n_i\right\}[u]=0
  \end{aligned}
  $$

and in book [Discontinuous Galerkin Method
Analysis and Applications to Compressible Flow](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-19267-3) it gives the same conclusion

- let triangulation $\mathscr{T}_h$ ( $h>0$ is a parameter) be a partition of the closure $\bar{\Omega}$ of the domain $\Omega$ into a finite number of closed $d$-dimensional simplexes $K$ with mutually disjoint interiors such that
  $$
  \bar{\Omega}=\bigcup_{K \in \mathscr{T}_h} K
  $$
- The discontinuous Galerkin method is based on the use of discontinuous approximations. This is the reason that over a triangulation $\mathscr{T}_h$, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we define the so-called broken Sobolev space
  $$
  H^k\left(\Omega, \mathscr{T}_h\right)=\left\{v \in L^2(\Omega) ;\left.v\right|_K \in H^k(K) \forall K \in \mathscr{T}_h\right\},
  $$ which consists of functions, whose restrictions on $K \in \mathscr{T}_h$ belong to the Sobolev space $H^k(K)$. On the other hand, functions from $H^k\left(\Omega, \mathscr{T}_h\right)$ are, in general, discontinuous on inner faces of elements $K \in \mathscr{T}_h$.
- Let $\Gamma \in \mathscr{F}_h^I$ and let $K_{\Gamma}^{(L)}, K_{\Gamma}^{(R)} \in \mathscr{T}_h$ be elements adjacent to $\Gamma$. For $v \in$ $H^1\left(\Omega, \mathscr{T}_h\right)$ we introduce the following notation:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  & v_{\Gamma}^{(L)}=\text { the trace of }\left.v\right|_{K_{\Gamma}^{(L)}} \text { on } \Gamma, \\
  & v_{\Gamma}^{(R)}=\text { the trace of }\left.v\right|_{K_{\Gamma}^{(R)}} \text { on } \Gamma, \\
  & \langle v\rangle_{\Gamma}=\frac{1}{2}\left(v_{\Gamma}^{(L)}+v_{\Gamma}^{(R)}\right) \quad(\text { mean value of the traces of } v \text { on } \Gamma), \\
  & {[v]_{\Gamma}=v_{\Gamma}^{(L)}-v_{\Gamma}^{(R)} \quad(\text { jump of } v \text { on } \Gamma) .}
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Due to the assumption that $u \in H^2(\Omega)$, we have
  $$
  [u]_{\Gamma}=[\nabla u]_{\Gamma}=0, \quad \nabla u_{\Gamma}^{(L)}=\nabla u_{\Gamma}^{(R)}=\langle\nabla u\rangle_{\Gamma}, \quad \Gamma \in \mathscr{F}_h^I
  $$

My question is how to derive the above conclusion for jump and average from the properties of the $H^2$ and $H^1$ space when functions are known to be discontinuous on all inner faces of elements in triangulation

Comment: Please type out the question, pictures are not searchable. Also, please indicate what specifically is unclear to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a beginner in the discontinuous Galerkin method and do not have much knowledge of functional analysis. This question has been bothering me for hours

Comment: It is not quite clear from the body of our post, but is your domain in two or three spatial dimensions? I believe that this question can be answered by the Sobolev embedding theorem, which gives results on when $H^k(\Omega)$ functions and their derivatives are continuous based on the dimension of the space $\Omega$ lies in.

Comment: Interesting question. As whpowell96 mentioned it would be interesting to know which spatial dimension we are working with.

Comment: As long as the dimension is $\leq 3$, any function of $H^2$ on a sufficiently regular set is continuous by Sobolev-Morrey embedding.  In your definition of $[u]$ in the post, it should be $-$ instead of $*$.

Comment: @whpowell96 $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $R^d,  d \leq 3$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that if $u\in H^2$, then $\nabla u\in H^1$. Therefore if we can show that $[u]=0$ a.e. for internal faces when $u\in H^1$, we can deduce the analogous property for $[\nabla u\cdot n]$ if $u\in H^2$.

Now, as $C^\infty$ is dense in $H^1$, there is a sequence $u_k\in C^\infty$ such that $\|u-u_k\|_{H^1}\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. Since these functions are smooth it is clear that they have zero jump over internal faces. Therefore, by applying the trace theorem we find that for an internal face $F$,
$$\|[u]\|_{L^2(F)}=\|[u-u_k]\|_{L^2(F)}\le C\sum_{K\in\mathscr{T}_h:K\cap F\ne\emptyset}\|u-u_k\|_{H^1(K)}\to 0$$
as $k\to\infty$.

Notice that this result holds more generally than relying on Sobolev embeddings.